# Exceeding time limit with adding sorting structure in Google Drive with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on a folder structure where I would like to reinforce a folder structure for the image assets that are being stored under a certain folder. However, it seems like the script is exceeding the time limit (6mins), and I'm not too sure how should I improve the run time of this script.

Potentially, I would like to add a check function to make sure that I don't create the folder tree with the same name as detected.

```js
function addtomisc() {

  var testfile = DriveApp.getFolderById('0BzKUBFemk1xic3RqeWJ4OFVYeFE');
  var insidetestfile = testfile.getFolders();

  while (insidetestfile.hasNext()) {
    var folderinside = insidetestfile.next();

    //Create nested folders under Marketing Material
    var marketingmaterial = folderinside.createFolder("Marketing Material");
    marketingmaterial.createFolder("Banners");
    marketingmaterial.createFolder("Logo");
    marketingmaterial.createFolder("Posters");
    marketingmaterial.createFolder("Product Materials");

    //Create nested folders under Nutritional Labels
    var nutritional = folderinside.createFolder("Nutritional Labels");
    nutritional.createFolder("Hong Kong");
    nutritional.createFolder("China");
    nutritional.createFolder("Original");

    //Create nested folders under Product Images
    var productimage = folderinside.createFolder("Product Images");
    productimage.createFolder("Originals");
    productimage.createFolder("Shopify optimized");
    productimage.createFolder("Stolen from Web");

    //Create a Misc folder for don't know what's going on
    var misc = folderinside.createFolder("Misc");

  }
}
```

I'm quite new to Javascript

Comment: Have you used your run log? This will show you the times per execution in your script. It will quickly highlight where the majority of the time is being left. I suspect that a lot of the time will be in creating the folders.

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but does it mean that creating folders will take a lot of time to run?

Comment: Yes, creating/moving/deleting folders often take quite a bit of runtime. Thats why I said look at your runtime log, this will show you the calls and how long it took for that call to be completed.